# Where to put the word "normally" correctly in the following sentence?

Tags: syntax

Where is the right place to put the word (adv.) normally in the following sentence? I have thought on the following options but I'm not sure which one of them is the most correct or sounds natural.

a) The total camel body water **normally** **is** between 50 to 70 percent.

b) The total camel body water **is** **normally** between 50 to 70 percent.

c) The total camel body water is between 50 to 70 percent, **normally**.

Comment: We use the singular _percent,_ not the plural _percent**s**._

Comment: All are correct, but b) would be the most common. But eliminate the second *is* - I assume that's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three of your sentences are correct and understandable, it is a matter of style.

Also

> *Normally*, the total camel body water is between 50 to 70 percents.

is correct.

Comment: And don't forget _A normal camel's body water is between 50 to 70 percent._

Comment: @P.E.Dant +1 "A normal camel's **total** body water is between 50 to 70 percent." ;-)

Comment: Well, _total_ is superfluous here, isn't it? The assumption, absent a qualification, is that the entire camel is under discussion, and not just some portion of it!

Comment: True, but I thought it keeps the OP's original words and then they can see how things move around with different phrasing... but maybe that's just me...

Comment: Don't mind me, I'm just trying half-heartedly to justify, after the fact, the omission of _total_ from my example.